# join in mysql need to return single record for each primary key

Tags: mysql

I have two tables for properties and images Which have the same column name like id,name in both tables. parent column is a foreign key in images.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(A.id),A.name,B.name AS img 
FROM `jos_properties_products` AS A
LEFT JOIN `jos_properties_images` AS B ON A.id = B.parent
```

[image]

From the above i want to remove duplicate.

Comment: you meant remove the duplicate name?

Comment: yes. I want to remove the duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
 SELECT A.id,A.name,max(B.name) AS img 
FROM `jos_properties_products` AS A
LEFT JOIN `jos_properties_images` AS B ON A.id = B.parent
group by A.id,A.name
```

Comment: Shall i know why we have to use max() ?

Comment: you have multiple B.name associated with single id-name combination. Here you want to avoid id-name duplicates. So for each id-name take the  maximum value of B.name.  you can use min() also instead of max()

Answer (score 0):

SELECT DISTINCT(A.id) as ids,A.name aName,B.name AS img 
FROM `jos_properties_products` AS A
LEFT JOIN `jos_properties_images` AS B ON A.id = B.parent group by ids,aName,img;

I think this will do